# Convert String into integer value

Tags: python-3.x, string, types, integer

I need to make following string:

```
amount = "$163,852.06"
```

Like this:

```
16385206000
```

How can I do it, like I am following this method,:

```
money = "$163,852.06"
original_amount = ('').join(money[1:].split(','))
print(int(float(original_amount)))
```

But it is returning me:

```
163852
```

Comment: `16385206000` doesn't look like what it should be.

Comment: `int(float(amount[1:].replace(',','')) * 100000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> int(''.join(c for c in amount if c.isdigit()))*1000
16385206000
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're casting a floating point to an integer value, which rounds to the nearest full number. To achieve the value 16385206000, you could use `int(float(original_amount) * 100000)`.